# Java enhanced for loop with range

Tags: foreach, range

When did the Java-enhanced for loop attain the following range capability?

```
for int index : [0, array,length] {...}
```

Comment: Is this a generic question for curiosity or are you trying to solve a problem that was caused by the addition of this new capability? Please update your question to identify what problem you are trying to solve or this question might be listed as off-topic.

Comment: Just a question as to what version released that form of the enhanced for loop became available.